# How do I find out (command line or python) if an IP address is from the local host?

Tags: terminal, network, python

I am running macOS High Sierra and Mojave.

I'd like to be able to find out (for a python script) if some IP address is from the local machine or another machine. The local machine may have multiple IP addresses (such as one for ethernet and one for wifi) which both are active on the local machine (even if only one is used to connect to the LAN).

I've found a way, `route get <ip-address>` will show *interface: lo0* in the output for any IP address that is from an interface of the local host.

Default route (ethernet):

```
hermione:~ gerben$ route get 192.168.1.10
   route to: hermione
destination: hermione
  interface: lo0
      flags: <UP,HOST,DONE,LLINFO,WASCLONED,LOCAL,IFSCOPE,IFREF>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0     16384         0
```

The other ip address (Wifi, not the default route when ethernet is connected) on this host:

```
hermione:~ gerben$ route get 192.168.1.11
   route to: 192.168.1.11
destination: 192.168.1.11
  interface: lo0
      flags: <UP,HOST,DONE,LLINFO,WASCLONED,LOCAL,IFSCOPE,IFREF>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0     16384         0
```

I don't know how reliable that is, but I could parse that. Update: this only works on Mojave, High Sierra will not report that it is local.

Is there a better way by which I can determine if some random IP address is in fact on a local interface? One that works on more versions of macOS?

Preferably directly in python 3, so I don't have to run external commands and parse their output in python.

At the request of @Allan, the output of `ifconfig` (Mojave)

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>

en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
    ether f0:18:98:ed:f6:45 
    inet6 fe80::1040:443f:fe24:97e8%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x8 
    inet 192.168.1.10 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex,flow-control>)
    status: active
en9: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether ac:de:48:00:11:22 
    inet6 fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en9 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active

en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether f0:18:98:b6:d3:d0 
    inet 192.168.1.11 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active

awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 12:69:24:84:fd:9a 
    inet6 fe80::1069:24ff:fe84:fd9a%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xd 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active

vboxnet0: flags=8842<BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
vboxnet1: flags=8842<BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 
vboxnet2: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:02 
    inet 192.168.97.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.97.255
```

I can egrep `'init.*192\.168\.1\.11'` on that to get the ip-addresses of the interfaces on this host.

Comment: You could also parse the output of `ifconfig`, but using `route` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Maybe I am interested in an `ifconfig` method as I just found out my `route` route ;-) doesn't work on High Sierra

Comment: `lo0` is your loopback interface.  It's a pseudo interface created by the system so it will be local no matter what.  I've read this question several times and it seems that you're asking to determine if *any* given IP address is on the local subnet or not.  Is that correct?

Comment: I've adapted the question to make it more clear

Comment: I've removed the inactive/irrelevant interfaces and only left the active ones.  The first thing I can see is that you have a multi-homed setup with WiFi and Ethernet both connected to the same network - this is not ideal.  If you're connected via Ethernet, turn off WiFi.  There's no reason to have both on simultaneously.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out of you attempting to determine if any IP (meaning any IP from anywhere in the world) is routed through a particular interface or if you happen to be on a particular network.

Comment: No, that _is_ ideal. Basically, if the ethernet link is broken, the system falls back on  the next interface, which is Wifi. This is a normal setup, especially on laptops that may be either. Normally, I have Wifi turned off on desktops (indeed: no need), but for testing I want to have both active. In a perfect world, it would both be the same IP address and traffic could use both, but creating such bonded setups is way too complex and probably doesn't work in most cases anyway.

Comment: I am not trying to do either. I want to know if a certain IP is 'me'. Because if it is not 'me' I need to do something in my script and if it is 'me' I need to do something else. So in my example, if I give my script IP-address 192.168.1.13 I have to do one thing and if I give it 192.168.1.10 or 192.168.1.11 I have to do something else.

Comment: for python library see https://pypi.org/project/netifaces/ or https://pythonhosted.org/ifaddr/

Comment: So basically you can run `ifconfig | fgrep IP`, if you find a match the address is local.

Comment: Try out `sudo netstat -anp tcp` output will provide you a column named `Local Address` with your actual local addresses as you might guess. `sudo lsof -Pn -i4` will give you even more details, thou that's not what you asked for it might be useful.

Comment: @igor-voltaic both won't report an active but not default interface. I.e. 192.168.1.10 is ethernet (default) and 192.168.1.11 is Wifi (secondary). 192.168.1.11 is a local address for my use, but will not be found with your `netstat` or `lsof` commands. `ifconfig` with grep works.

Comment: @gctwnl you are right about `lsof`, but statement is not true for `netstat`. try `netstat -i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to figure this out for some customers in the past. Easiest and most reliable method across OS versions I've found is string matching inet lines in ifconfig results.

Answer (score 0):

`netstat` is the tool meant for that.

`netstat -i` will display your interfaces and IPs associated with them

here is the link with [more examples](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-netstat-command-examples/) and `man netstat` of course the next thing to read to get more details.